# Aggregate an entire data frame with Weighted Mean

Tags: r, aggregate, weighted-average

I'm trying to aggregate a data frame using the function `weighted.mean` and continue to get an error.  My data looks like this:

`dat <- data.frame(date, nWords, v1, v2, v3, v4 ...)`

I tried something like:

`aggregate(dat, by = list(dat$date), weighted.mean, w = dat$nWords)`

but got

```
 Error in weighted.mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

There is another thread which answers this question using plyr but for only one variable, I want to aggregate all my variables that way.

Comment: Is it an issue that you misspelled `weighted.mean` in your code?

Comment: I believe `weighted.mean` expects `w` to be the length of the chunk sliced by `aggregate`, which corresponds to the number of elements per factor level (or the combination). You can thus use only one weight, assuming number of elements per factor level is equal. You should probably write a custom function and use `mapply` to prepare `w` for `aggregate`ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with data.table:

```
 library(data.table)

 #set up your data

 dat <- data.frame(date = c("2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2013-01-01",
 "2013-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01"), 
 nwords = 1:9, v1 = rnorm(9), v2 = rnorm(9), v3 = rnorm(9))

 #make it into a data.table

 dat = data.table(dat, key = "date")

 # grab the column names we want, generalized for V1:Vwhatever

 c = colnames(dat)[-c(1,2)]

 #get the weighted mean by date for each column

 for(n in c){
 dat[,
     n := weighted.mean(get(n), nwords),
     with = FALSE,
     by = date]
 }

 #keep only the unique dates and weighted means

 wms = unique(dat[,nwords:=NULL])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `by`:

```
# your numeric data
x <- 111:120

# the weights
ww <- 10:1 

mat <- cbind(x, ww)

# the group variable (in your case is 'date')
y <- c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 3))

by(data=mat, y, weighted.mean)
```

If you want the results in a data frame, I suggest the `plyr` package:

```
plyr::ddply(data.frame(mat), "y", weighted.mean)
```